# How to print key when value exist in dictionary

Tags: python

How to print key, when string exist in value of dictionary?

For example my dictinary look as below:

```
d = {}

with open(filename) as document:
    for row in csv.reader(document, delimiter='\t'):
        d[row[0]] = row[1:]
        #print(d)

with open(filename) as file:
    for k,v in d.items():
        print(v)
```

filename is tab-separated txt.file for example:

```
hello hello1 hello2 hello3
hell2 hell3  hell4  hell5
```

I want print value of key, when string is equal value.
For example i have input: hello1 i want to print : hello, hello1
If i have input : hell2, i want to print : hell2, hell2.

Always i want key value in first column, second column is input value.

Comment: Your example would be clearer if you only had two columns (which is all your csv.reader() code seems interested in), and used different words for the two columns (e.g. key0, key1, key2,...; val0, val1, val2,... ). Does your question boil-down to just needing to flip your dictionary from key->val into val->key?

Comment: "For example my dictinary look as below" I would expect you to actually show how the dictionary looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is confusing, just try neat approach with simple dict comprehension :

```
with open('file','r') as f:
    data={line.split()[0]:line.split()[1:] for line in f}

while True:
    user_input=input("Input >> ")
    if user_input=='quit':
        break
    else:
        if user_input in data:
            print(data[user_input],'\n')
```

output:

```
Input >> hello
['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3'] 

Input >> hell2
['hell3', 'hell4', 'hell5'] 

Input >> quit

Process finished with exit code 0
```